# The name of a construction from two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Then suppose there exist continuous maps
$$f\colon X\to Y$$
$$g\colon Y\to X.$$
Then the following construction may be made:

Define an equivalence relation on the disjoint union of $X\times[0,1]$ and $Y\times[0,1]$ where $(x,0)\sim (y, 1)$ for all $y\in Y$ such that $g(y)=x$, and $(y, 0)\sim (x, 1)$ for all $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. The ensuing topological space will "look" like the following:

[image]

Does this space have a name?

Comment: As far as I can tell the construction is, up to homeomorphism, the *double mapping cylinder* of $X\xleftarrow{1_X+g}X\sqcup Y\xrightarrow{f+1_Y}Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of closely related well known objects such as [mapping cylinders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cylinder), [mapping tori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_torus) and [mapping telesopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cylinder#Mapping_telescope).

But I have not seen any terminology for your object. Nonetheless you could probably coin a useful term which related your object to these other more familiar objects.

How about "two step mapping torus"? Or something like that?

What would be even better (if there were some use for it) would be if there were some universal terminology which applied to any diagram of arrows in the category of topological spaces...